# Redirect from http to https ONLY IF https is available

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I use an in-house content management system written using PHP and running on Apache and Linux. The CMS has an install routine that automatically creates a .htaccess file that forces the redirect of http to https for all new isntallations. This is all good if https is installed on that domain, but my question is, **how can I modify the test so that .htaccess only forwards to https if https is available for that domain?**

The important part of the .htaccess file:

```
# Redirect users from http: to https:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why not test for HTTPS first (within the install script) and then only install the `RewriteRule` if HTTPS was found. Alternatively (and possible better) ask the user at the start of the install. Not everyone may want to be forced to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well the way to do it is first not to use `mod_rewrite` (pursing to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) and use `Redirect` in its place:

```
Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
```